# jQuery Mobile is removing my classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
    <div class="top-row">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/default-user.gif" width="45" height="45" alt="" class="avatar left">
            <a href="#" id="expand-footer" data-role="none">Expand</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

and JS that expands the footer:

```
toggleFooter: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $footer = $('footer');

        if(footer_expanded) {
            $footer.animate({height:'50px'}, 500, function() {
                $('#expand-footer').toggleClass('expanded');
            });
        } else {
            $footer.animate({height:'550px'}, 500, function() {
                $('#expand-footer').toggleClass('expanded');
            });
        }
        footer_expanded = !footer_expanded;
    }
```

the toggleFooter function is called by this:

```
$('#expand-footer').on('click', events.toggleFooter);
```

the problem I am having is that as soon as the expanded class is added, JQuery Mobile removes it.

Thanks

Comment: Just my 2 cents but you should not use toggleClass in animate callback function, can give unexpected result. Try using removeClass() and addClass() methods instead and see if it fixes issue.

Comment: what calls `toggleFooter`?

Comment: I tried that too. I had a separate function to toggle the button. I just posted it here with toggleClass for the sake of not pasting any other irrelevant code

Comment: it's called by $('#expand-footer').on('click', events.toggleFooter);

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case but jQuery Mobile has events for expandable content named `expand` and `contract`. I'd assume they use that same verbiage for class names. Have you tried changing the `expanded` class to something else? I'd go for something like `aAFjt2` (totally random) just to make sure this isn't the issue. You should setup a JSFiddle of the situation though, because it seems like there may be something else causing the problem. A lot of the time the issue is a race-condition problem since jQM is so AJAXy.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, as I didn't have time to really dig into the issue:

```
toggleButton: function() {
        var $btn = $('#expand-footer');

        if(footer_expanded) {
            $btn.css({'background-position':'left bottom'});
        } else {
            $btn.css({'background-position':'left top'});
        }
    }
```

this works, as there's no class for jQuery Mobile to remove :)

Answer (score 0):

I 've built a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m54r/) from your question. The class `expanded` is *not* removed by this code. There must be something else (other code), which triggers this, if `expanded` is really removed.

Comment: It has something to do with jQuery Mobile. If I remove it from the page, my code works perfectly fine. But I need jQuery Mobile to keep the footer fixed at the bottom on the iPad.

Comment: @petermk It isn't triggered by the code you have shown. Modify the JSFiddle and try to reproduce it there. Then add a link to the new JSFiddle to your question.